# How to view the Build Log

Tags: cctray

I keep having a failed build when building to the server. I need to find out why it's failing. How to I view the log to see what files I'm missing or what is causing the build to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the project being failed in cctray window, right click on it and go to "Display web page". It'll open corresponding page where you can pick the latest build to check what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Double click on failed project in cctray should open the links in browers where you can view build log OR alternatively if you have access, can visit server work space + Artifacts\buildlogs